# Where can I obtain the sefer “Titen Emes L'Yaakov”?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, emes-truth-honesty

Rabbi D Neustadt referenced a sefer “Titen Emes L'Yaakov” in his “Weekly Halacha Discussion” titled “The Halachic Definition of a Lie”. Can someone tell me where I can obtain this sefer please? (I sent an email to Rav Neustadt without success.)

Comment: There are many sefarim with this title (as a google search shows) - what was the content of the sefer? And if you don't know, why would you care which Titen Emes L'Yaakov it is?

Comment: Rav Yaakov  Edelstein?

Comment: @רבות מחשבות Content of the sefer: The halachos of truth and lies.

Comment: Is the author R' Ya'akov Peretz? Then Moriah Bookstore can send it(moriah.co).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book in question is probably from the contemporary, R. Yaakov Chizkiah Fisch.

The full book is online [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/56594).